# Memory Consistency on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory

I was reading this [article](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Ebornholt/post/memory-models.html) on general memory consistency and it raised some questions for me about memory consistency on iOS. It's a really interesting article, but it doesn't go into too many specifics about general platforms. The article mentions that languages such as C++ (and I'm guessing Objective-C/Cocoa Touch APIs) use sequential consistency for data-race-free programs to remove many of the weird behaviors that may occur when trying to write to the same memory.

So, say if I were to use Grand Central Dispatch to create a bunch of different threads, would it even be possible to declare and use global variables that are stored on the same location in memory? If so, how would the writing and reading process work? Is there a write buffer? I would test out some of this stuff if I could, but at the moment I cannot. Anything to help me understand this concept would be appreciated.

Comment: This is really too broad of a question for this forum, which is far more targeted to "What did you try and why didn't it do what you wanted?" type questions.